# Google Play Services/Maps NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I implemented the [Google Maps tutorial from this link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidGoogleMaps%2Farticle.html&ei=A1D5VNiuDoaMuATZk4GoBA&usg=AFQjCNE9PiJJYUNOYNayRkahyUHhhqsU0A&sig2=zZP-chZEcbrJtPtjYn1Xfw&bvm=bv.87611401,d.c2E). But I'm getting a runtime error and the app crashes. Please help me.I followed other similar questions but haven't been able to find a solution. The issue seems to be after I updated Google Play Services.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.sahayog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL) 
        .title("Kiel") 
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
     // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override 
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true; 
  }

}
```

Logcat:

```
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319): Process:  com.example.sahayog, PID: 12319
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at com.example.sahayog.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:16)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sahayog-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   ... 15 more
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):       ... 16 more
     03-06 12:21:26.660: E/AndroidRuntime(12319):   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Can you format your code please

Comment: @TimCastelijns Done ! Sorry for posting without proper formatting.

Comment: Main error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hackerearth.sahayog-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].

Comment: @Nielarshi I couldn't understand how to fix that. :(

Comment: You have a problem with the jar file that you are using for google maps API. Check the jar or else download proper jar. You can decompile the jar and see regarding classes. Class file is not present as it is mentioned in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        // Google Play Services are not available
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        // Google Play Services are available
        map = ((MapFragment)   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
       Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
       .title("Hamburg"));
       Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
      .position(KIEL) 
      .title("Kiel") 
      .snippet("Kiel is cool")
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

      // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
     // Zoom in, animating the camera.
     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
```